# Splitting a mac desktop into smaller portions

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, desktop

## Background

I'm using a device called a DualHead2Go that lets me plug two external screens into an early gen Macbook Pro. This device basically presents the two screens to the mac as if they were one gigantic 3840x1080 screen.

[image: DualHead2Go Layout]

The macbook's internal screen is on the right

## The Problem

For the most part this setup works really well - the problem I have is that, as far as the Mac is concerned, the middle of this desktop is right in the break between displays. Which leads to situations like this:

[image: Items being split between displays]

Since this is my primary display, notifications and modal dialogs often come up right in the monitor split - not only is this ugly, it's a PITA to deal with.

## Solutions

In order of preference:

- Some application that would make the Mac work as if the "one display" were actually two. If this were a Linux box, I could do some trickery inside Xorg to present the one display as two.
- Some application that would allow me to tile windows, taking the display into account

  - I've tried applications like [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) before, the problem there is that they don't cleanly divide the desktop, leading to windows overhanging the split
- A tiling window manager, or some other application that allows me to divide my desktop space into set pieces, *including* where dialogs and notifications pop up.

Are any of these viable?

### Questions this is **NOT** a duplicate of:

[Is there a way to Split one 42 Inch TV into Multiple Displays or Virtual Displays?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30063/is-there-a-way-to-split-one-42-inch-tv-into-multiple-displays-or-virtual-display) (More than *four* years old, and the one answer to the question doesn't actually answer the question)

[How applications behave with Matrox Dualhead2go?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50609/how-applications-behave-with-matrox-dualhead2go) (More than two years old - the application situation might have changed)

Comment: Not an answer, but I think the core of the issue is that you're using a device that purposefully makes this hard by presenting your multiple screens as one. Maybe it would be easier to get an adapter that allows them to connect, but still be recognized as separate screens.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [PowerDesk for Mac](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_me/?productTabs=2)? the description says it can do what you want. There's a [DualHead2Go & TripleHead2Go User Guide for Mac](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/pdf/products/gxm/en_gxm_mac_user_guide.pdf). PowerDesk for Mac can be [downloaded](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/gxm/drivers/) for 10.6 thru 10.10. See [Download info](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/drivers/download/?id=599).

Okay, instead of preferences in order, from your comment they're ***all*** requirements.

Try a combo of PowerDesk for Mac, [Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) and [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/).

Comment: Doesn't do what I want, unfortunately. It can differentiate between the screens, but the window management is limited to giving you a hotkey to fullscreen an application on one physical monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BetterDummy](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDummy) to make your virtual displays, then do PIP window streaming without title bar. NOTE that the PIP streaming is only available with the $15 Pro version. As far as I have used it, it doesn't have problems with gaps between virtual screens.